# how does Enumerable#cycle work? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, enumerable

```
looper = (0..3).cycle
20.times { puts looper.next }
```

can I somehow find the next of 3? I mean if I can get `.next` of any particular element at any given time. Not just display loop that starts with the first element.

### **UPDATE**

Of course I went though ruby [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Enumerable.html#M003054) before posting my question. But I did not find answer there ...

### **UPDATE2**

**input**

`looper = (0..max_cycle).cycle`

`max_cycle` = variable that can be different every time the script runs

`looper` = variable that is always from interval (0..max_cycle) but the current value when the script starts could be any. It is based on `Time.now.hour`

**output**

I want to know `.next` value of `looper` at any time during the running time of the script

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  What is your expected input and output?

Comment: yeah,I thought I wasn't maybe so clear. Please see update2

Comment: That update just says that you read the docs. It doesn't clarify your question...

Comment: @Jimmy Cuadra: Update2 wasn't there yet. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Maybe you want something like this?

```
(current_value + 1) % (max_cycle + 1)
```

If, for example, `max_cycle = 3` you will have the following output:

```
current_value    returns
      0             1
      1             2
      2             3
      3             0
```

Comment: @Teoulas: :-) that's what I want. Can I use Enumerable#cycle for that?

Comment: @Radek, I don't think so. Enumerable objects are used to iterate over a collection of values/objects. In your case, you only need the first and the last number of a range. If you insist on calling a method, you could add one to ruby's Range.

eg. (0..3).next_with_wrap(2) => 3

Comment: I don't insist on anything. I'm looking for the best solution and learning on way... I wrote a method but I thought there must be something simpler then Enumerable#cycle came along. I thought I could use it. That's it. Your solution is much nices, easier than my method. I am happy with that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Enumerable.html#M003074

Comment: Of course I went though ruby doc before posting my question. But I did not find answer there ...